# Zend_Db WHERE NOT

Tags: mysql, zend-db, where-clause

I'm in need of building a query like this in with Zend_Db:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE NOT (field1 = 0.00 AND field2 = 0.00  AND field3 = 0.00);
```

How can I accomplish this with Zend_Db, also is the MySQL approach correct? (if all three fields are 0.00 then ignore it).

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
$db->select()
    ->from('mytable')
    ->where('field1 != 0.00')
    ->where('field2 != 0.00')
    ->where('field3 != 0.00');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
$query = $this->select()
              ->from('mytable')
              ->where('field1 <> ? AND field2 <> ? AND field3 <> ?', 0, 2) /*2 is Zend_Db::FLOAT_TYPE*/
```